# How to get columns from different unrelated tables having similar column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

Pay Group:

```
PayGroupId   Name       Description    Code
1            US Weekly  US Weekly      USW
2            Can Weekly Canada Weekly  CANW
3            US Monthly US Monthly     USM
4            Can Monthly Can Monthly   CANM
```

Pay Type:

```
PayTypeId   Name       Description    Code
1           Hourly     Hourly         H
2           Salary     Salaried       S
```

Pay Code:

```
PayCodeId   Name       Description    Code
1           Regular    Regular        REG
2           PTO        PTO            PTO
3           Sick       Sick           SICK
```

I need a report in following format:

```
PayGroup    PayType    PayCode
US Weekly   Hourly     Regular
Can Weekly  Salary     PTO        
US Monthly             Sick
```

Can we do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *suspect* this gets you the result you are after, but seems like an odd requirement:

```
WITH PG AS(
    SELECT [Name],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PayGroupID ASC) AS RN
    FROM PayGroup),
PT AS(
    SELECT [Name],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PayTypeID ASC) AS RN
    FROM PayGroup),
PC AS(
    SELECT [Name],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PayCodeID ASC) AS RN
    FROM PayCode)
SELECT PG.[Name] AS PayGroup,
       PT.[Name] AS PayType,
       PC.[Name] AS PayCode
FROM PG
     FULL OUTER JOIN PT ON PG.RN = PT.RN
     FULL OUTER JOIN PC ON PG.RN = PC.RN
                        OR PT.RN = PC.RN;
```

Comment: One quick question.... What if the Primary Key of the tables start with different number? for example, for Pay Code, the PayCode ID starts with 100 and for Pay Type the PayTypeId starts with 28?

Comment: @user1326379 seems you don't understand the answer. Do you understand what `ROW_NUMBER` does?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
    ([PayGroupId] int, [Name] varchar(11), [Description] varchar(13), [Code] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #table1
    ([PayGroupId], [Name], [Description], [Code])
VALUES
    (1, 'US Weekly', 'US Weekly', 'USW'),
    (2, 'Can Weekly', 'Canada Weekly', 'CANW'),
    (3, 'US Monthly', 'US Monthly', 'USM'),
    (4, 'Can Monthly', 'Can Monthly', 'CANM')
;


CREATE TABLE #table2
    ([PayTypeId] int, [Name] varchar(6), [Description] varchar(8), [Code] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO #table2
    ([PayTypeId], [Name], [Description], [Code])
VALUES
    (1, 'Hourly', 'Hourly', 'H'),
    (2, 'Salary', 'Salaried', 'S')
;




CREATE TABLE #table3
    ([PayCodeId] int, [Name] varchar(7), [Description] varchar(7), [Code] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #table3
    ([PayCodeId], [Name], [Description], [Code])
VALUES
    (1, 'Regular', 'Regular', 'REG'),
    (2, 'PTO', 'PTO', 'PTO'),
    (3, 'Sick', 'Sick', 'SICK')
;
select a.name PayGroup ,isnull(B.Name,'') PayType ,isnull(C.Name,'')PayCode
 from #table1 A left join #table2 B on a.[PayGroupId]=b.[PayTypeId]left join
 #table3 c on c.[PayCodeId]=a.[PayGroupId]


PayGroup    PayType PayCode
US Weekly   Hourly  Regular
Can Weekly  Salary  PTO
US Monthly          Sick
Can Monthly
```